# CSS: position of the header shifts to right when a radio button is clicked

Tags: html, css

I created a set of radio (black red white blue). Each radio button will display another set of radio button accordingly on clicked. But there's an issue where the position of the header "weighta" shifted to right when the color radio button was clicked

[image]

Also would like to ask if there's any better way to code these radio button onclick show/hide?

```js
 function onLoad() {
    //method for button times
    var group1 = document.getElementById("group1");
    group1.classList.remove('hide');
    group1.classList.add('show');

    var group2 = document.getElementById("group2");
    group2.classList.remove('show');
    group2.classList.add('hide');

    var group3 = document.getElementById("group3");
    group3.classList.remove('show');
    group3.classList.add('hide');

    var group4 = document.getElementById("group4");
    group4.classList.remove('show');
    group4.classList.add('hide');
  }


  function onLoad2() {
    //method for button times
    var group2 = document.getElementById("group2");
    group2.classList.remove('hide');
    group2.classList.add('show');

    var group1 = document.getElementById("group1");
    group1.classList.remove('show');
    group1.classList.add('hide');

    var group3 = document.getElementById("group3");
    group3.classList.remove('show');
    group3.classList.add('hide');

    var group4 = document.getElementById("group4");
    group4.classList.remove('show');
    group4.classList.add('hide');
  }

  function onLoad3() {
    //method for button times

    var group1 = document.getElementById("group1");
    group1.classList.remove('show');
    group1.classList.add('hide');

    var group2 = document.getElementById("group2");
    group2.classList.remove('show');
    group2.classList.add('hide');

    var group3 = document.getElementById("group3");
    group3.classList.remove('hide');
    group3.classList.add('show');

    var group4 = document.getElementById("group4");
    group4.classList.remove('show');
    group4.classList.add('hide');
  }

  function onLoad4() {
    //method for button times

    var group1 = document.getElementById("group1");
    group1.classList.remove('show');
    group1.classList.add('hide');

    var group2 = document.getElementById("group2");
    group2.classList.remove('show');
    group2.classList.add('hide');

    var group3 = document.getElementById("group3");
    group3.classList.remove('show');
    group3.classList.add('hide');

    var group4 = document.getElementById("group4");
    group4.classList.remove('hide');
    group4.classList.add('show');
  }
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }

.swatch{margin:1em 0;}
.swatch .header{margin:0.5em 0;}
.swatch input{display:none;}
.swatch label{-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;float:left;min-width:50px;height:35px;margin:0;border:#ccc 1px solid;background-color:#ddd;font-size:13px;text-align:center;line-height:35px;white-space:nowrap;text-transform:uppercase;}
.swatch-element label{padding:0 10px;}
.color.swatch-element label{padding:0;}
.swatch input:checked + label{-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);border-color:transparent;}
.swatch .swatch-element{float:left;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;margin:0px 10px 10px 0;position:relative;}
.crossed-out{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;}
.swatch .swatch-element .crossed-out{display:none;}
.swatch .swatch-element.soldout .crossed-out{display:block;}
.swatch .swatch-element.soldout label{filter:alpha(opacity=60);-khtml-opacity:0.6;-moz-opacity:0.6;opacity:0.6;}
.swatch .tooltip{text-align:center;background:gray;color:#fff;bottom:100%;padding:10px;display:block;position:absolute;width:100px;left:-23px;margin-bottom:15px;filter:alpha(opacity=0);-khtml-opacity:0;-moz-opacity:0;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;-webkit-transform:translateY(10px);-moz-transform:translateY(10px);-ms-transform:translateY(10px);-o-transform:translateY(10px);transform:translateY(10px);-webkit-transition:all .25s ease-out;-moz-transition:all .25s ease-out;-ms-transition:all .25s ease-out;-o-transition:all .25s ease-out;transition:all .25s ease-out;-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);-ms-box-shadow:2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);-o-box-shadow:2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);box-shadow:2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);z-index:10000;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
.swatch .tooltip:before{bottom:-20px;content:" ";display:block;height:20px;left:0;position:absolute;width:100%;}
.swatch .tooltip:after{border-left:solid transparent 10px;border-right:solid transparent 10px;border-top:solid gray 10px;bottom:-10px;content:" ";height:0;left:50%;margin-left:-13px;position:absolute;width:0;}
.swatch .swatch-element:hover .tooltip{filter:alpha(opacity=100);-khtml-opacity:1;-moz-opacity:1;opacity:1;visibility:visible;-webkit-transform:translateY(0px);-moz-transform:translateY(0px);-ms-transform:translateY(0px);-o-transform:translateY(0px);transform:translateY(0px);}
.swatch.error{background-color:#E8D2D2!important;color:#333!important;padding:1em;border-radius:5px;}
.swatch.error p{margin:0.7em 0;}
.swatch.error p:first-child{margin-top:0;}
.swatch.error p:last-child{margin-bottom:0;}
.swatch.error code{font-family:monospace;}
```

```html
<div class="swatch color clearfix" data-option-index="0">
  <div class="header">
    Product
  </div>
  <div data-value="black" class="swatch-element color black available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      black
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-black" checked="checked" name="option-0" value="MS" type="radio" onclick="onLoad();">
    <label for="swatch-0-black" style="background-color: black; background-image: url(./assets/images/black.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="red" class="swatch-element color red available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      red
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-red" name="option-0" value="red" type="radio" onclick="onLoad2()">
    <label for="swatch-0-red" style="background-color: red; background-image: url(./assets/images/red.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="white" class="swatch-element color white available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      white
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-white" name="option-0" value="white" type="radio" onclick="onLoad3()">
    <label for="swatch-0-white" style="background-color: white; background-image: url(./assets/images/white.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="blue" class="swatch-element color blue available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      blue
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-blue" name="option-0" value="blue" type="radio" onclick="onLoad4()">
    <label for="swatch-0-blue" style="background-color: blue; background-image: url(./assets/images/blue.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="1" id="group1">
  <div class="header">
    Weighta
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-small" name="length" value="1.52g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-small">
                        1.52g
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-medium" name="length" value="1.54g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-medium">
                        1.54g 
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-3" name="length" value="1.57g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-3">
                        1.57g
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group2">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="1.48g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        1.48g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-5" name="length" value="1.49g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-5">
                        1.49g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group3">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="1.34g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        1.34g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-5" name="length" value="1.44g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-5">
                        1.44g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-3" name="length" value="1.54g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-3">
                        1.54g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group4">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="0.96g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        0.96g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool! let me try to paste it into my html page

Comment: i see, it seems to work in snippet but it actually doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the script, delegate

I have wrapped in a container and use flex and fixed width header

Also I toggle the class

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const groups = [...document.querySelectorAll(".swatch")].slice(1); // drop the first div
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgtDiv = e.target.closest(".swatch-element")
    if (tgtDiv) {
      const groupId = tgtDiv.querySelector("input[type=radio]").dataset.group;
      groups.forEach(aGroup => aGroup.classList.toggle("hide", groupId !== aGroup.id))
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.swatch {
  margin: 1em 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.header { width:70px}
.hide { display: none; }

.swatch .header {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.swatch input {
  display: none;
}

.swatch label {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.swatch-element label {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.color.swatch-element label {
  padding: 0;
}

.swatch input:checked+label {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.swatch .swatch-element {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.crossed-out {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swatch .swatch-element .crossed-out {
  display: none;
}

.swatch .swatch-element.soldout .crossed-out {
  display: block;
}

.swatch .swatch-element.soldout label {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.swatch .tooltip {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: -23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  z-index: 10000;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swatch .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.swatch .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid gray 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.swatch .swatch-element:hover .tooltip {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.swatch.error {
  background-color: #E8D2D2!important;
  color: #333!important;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.swatch.error p {
  margin: 0.7em 0;
}

.swatch.error p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.swatch.error p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.swatch.error code {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="swatch color clearfix" id="container" data-option-index="0">
  <div class="header">
    Product
  </div>
  <div data-value="black" class="swatch-element color black available">
    <div class="tooltip">black</div>
    <input id="swatch-0-black" checked="checked" name="option-0" value="MS" type="radio" data-group="group1">
    <label for="swatch-0-black" style="background-color: black; background-image: url(./assets/images/black.png)"><img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt=""></label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="red" class="swatch-element color red available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      red
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-red" name="option-0" value="red" type="radio" data-group="group2">
    <label for="swatch-0-red" style="background-color: red; background-image: url(./assets/images/red.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="white" class="swatch-element color white available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      white
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-white" name="option-0" value="white" type="radio" data-group="group3">
    <label for="swatch-0-white" style="background-color: white; background-image: url(./assets/images/white.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="blue" class="swatch-element color blue available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      blue
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-blue" name="option-0" value="blue" type="radio" data-group="group4">
    <label for="swatch-0-blue" style="background-color: blue; background-image: url(./assets/images/blue.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="1" id="group1">
  <div class="header">
    Weighta
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-small" name="length" value="1.52g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-small">
                        1.52g
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-medium" name="length" value="1.54g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-medium">
                        1.54g 
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-3" name="length" value="1.57g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-3">
                        1.57g
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group2">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="1.48g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        1.48g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-5" name="length" value="1.49g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-5">
                        1.49g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group3">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="1.34g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        1.34g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-5" name="length" value="1.44g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-5">
                        1.44g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-3" name="length" value="1.54g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-3">
                        1.54g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group4">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="0.96g" type="radio">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        0.96g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this makes the code look nicer and much lesser work need to be done. I tried putting the 

`const groups = [...document.queySelectorAll("swatch")].slice(1); // drop the first div
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgtDiv = e.target.closest(".swatch-element")
  if (tgt) {
    const group = tgtDiv.querySelector("input[type=radio]").dataset.group;
    groups.forEach(aGroup => group.hidden = group !== aGroup)
  }
})` 

into script and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: do you have any suggestion on where can I learn all these things? appreciate

Comment: Million of sites. You need to put the script after the html before the </body> tag - alternatively wrap my code ‍ n `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { …. });`

Comment: @teivel Please see updated code. I fixed both your issues

Comment: omg, this is amazing. I was depressed for the whole day looking for steps to resolve the issue. I appreciate your effort and time to help me out. Cheers!

Comment: sorry i didnt mean to be rude. I just realized that thr's such feature (accept the answer). thank you once again